So, many errors with trying to get connect wallet to work from /anza-xyz/wallet-adapter urgent help requested create-react-app
I tried using chatgpt and any other resource I could find, here are my Walletbutton.js script, app.js, and my AppWalletProvider.. I'm using create-react-app.
//WalletButton.js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';

const WalletButton = () => {
    const { connected } = useWallet();
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Connect Wallet');

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        if (connected) {
            setButtonText('Buy');
            // Implement the buy logic here
        }
    }, [connected]);

    return (
        <button className="MainButton" onClick={handleClick}>
            {connected ? 'Buy' : 'Connect Wallet'}
        </button>
    );
};

export default WalletButton;```

and next,

```//AppWalletProvider.js
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
    PhantomWalletAdapter,
    SolflareWalletAdapter,
    TorusWalletAdapter,
    LedgerWalletAdapter
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';

const wallets = [
    new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
    new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
    new TorusWalletAdapter(),
    new LedgerWalletAdapter()
];

const AppWalletProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta')}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    {children}
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};

export default AppWalletProvider;

and finally the app.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './index.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import WalletButton from './components/WalletButton';
import { WalletModalProvider, WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
    PhantomWalletAdapter,
    SolflareWalletAdapter,
    TorusWalletAdapter,
    LedgerWalletAdapter
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';



//import { useImmer } from 'use-immer';
//import { Progress } from 'antd';


const wallets = [
  new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
  new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
  new TorusWalletAdapter(),
  new LedgerWalletAdapter()
];

const PaymentTypes = [
{
ID: 1,
PaymentName: 'Solana',
NameBrev: 'SOL',
USDRate: 172.11,
IconImg:'./images/Solana_Icon200px.png',
IsSelected: false,
},
{
ID: 2,
PaymentName: 'United States Dollar Coin',
NameBrev: 'USDC',
USDRate: 1,
IconImg:'./images/USDC_Icon200px.png',
IsSelected: false,
},
{
  ID: 3,
  PaymentName: 'United States Dollar',
  NameBrev: 'FIAT',
  USDRate: 1,
  IconImg:'./images/FIAT_Icon200px.png',
  IsSelected: false,
  },
];

const InputFields = [
{
id: 1,
type:'currency',
value: '',
placeholder: 'Enter amount',
},
{
id: 2,
type:'token',
value: '',
placeholder: 'Enter amount',
},
];

const presaleRate = 0.34;


export default function App() {

  const [currencyVal, setCurrencyVal] = useState('');
  const [tokenAmount, setTokenAmount] = useState('');
  const [PaymentOptionsLi, renderList] = useState(PaymentTypes);


  //const InputFArr = InputFields;
  
  function handleSelected(id){
    renderList(PaymentOptionsLi => PaymentOptionsLi.map(PaymentOption => PaymentOption.ID === id?{...PaymentOption, IsSelected: true} :{...PaymentOption, IsSelected: false}));
    resetInputValues();
  }
  
    const selectedPaymentType = PaymentOptionsLi.find(option => option.IsSelected);


    function handleCurrencyChange(event){
      const value = parseFloat(event.target.value);
      setCurrencyVal(value);
      if (selectedPaymentType) {
        const newTokenAmount = (value * selectedPaymentType.USDRate) / presaleRate;
        setTokenAmount(newTokenAmount.toFixed(2));
      }
    }

    function handleTokenChange(event) {
      const value = parseFloat(event.target.value);
      setTokenAmount(value);
      if (selectedPaymentType) {
        const newCurrencyVal = (value * presaleRate) / selectedPaymentType.USDRate;
        setCurrencyVal(newCurrencyVal.toFixed(2));
    }

  }

  

  
    //index through the the inputs
    //used when someone selects new exchange button.
  

  function resetInputValues(){
    setCurrencyVal('');
    setTokenAmount('');
  }
      //used when someone puts something into the input 'numbers only'
      //should update both fields and the you get: displays.
  







let tokensOwned = 0;
 



  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta')}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
 
    <div className='MainPanel'>
      <p className='LaunchHeader'style={{marginTop:'5px',marginBottom:'5px'}}>
         Time till launch 
      </p>
      <CountDownTimer/>
      <ICOprogress/>
      
        <h3 style={{color: 'whitesmoke', fontSize: 'medium', textAlign: 'center', 
        marginTop:'6px',marginBottom:'6px',fontWeight:350}}>
        You Own: {tokensOwned}
      </h3>
      
     
      <PaymentList paymentOP = {PaymentOptionsLi} onSelected={handleSelected}/>
      

     
      

     <div>
      <h5>
          
      </h5>
      <Inputlist
        inputFields={InputFields}
        currencyVal={currencyVal}
        tokenAmount={tokenAmount}
        handleCurrencyChange={handleCurrencyChange}
        handleTokenChange={handleTokenChange}

      />
     </div>
     <div>
        <WalletButton/>
        
     </div>
     <div>
     <footer style={{color: 'white',textAlign:'center',fontSize:11,fontWeight:600}}>
          Wallet connected: N/A
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    </WalletModalProvider>
    </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>

  );
}



function ICOprogress(){

  let TokensSold = 0;
  let TokenPool = 30000000;
 const ProgressRate = (TokensSold / TokenPool) * 100;

return(
<div>
    
  <div>
  <p style= {{marginBottom: '3px', color:'#cbcbcb', fontWeight:50,fontSize:12,textAlign: 'center'}}>Tokens sold: {TokensSold} / {TokenPool}</p>
    <section className = 'TokenMeter'>
      <section className='TokenMeter-fill' style={{width: `${ProgressRate}%`}}></section>
      </section>
  </div>
</div>
)
}

function CountDownTimer(){
return(<div className='CountDown'>
  90:00:00:00
</div>
)
}


function PaymentList({paymentOP,onSelected}){

//let PaymentsSel = PaymentOptionsLi;

  return(


  <section className={'PaymentTyeBtn'} style={{marginBottom:'-10px'}} >
    {paymentOP.map((payOP) =>(
    <PaymentType payOP={payOP}
      onSelected={onSelected}
      key = {payOP.ID}/>))}
  </section>
)
}


function PaymentType({payOP,onSelected}){
  
  //let PaymentOp = {PaymentOptionsLi};

  console.log('contents of PaymentOP are,',payOP);
  return(
    <li style ={{display:'inline'}}>
      <button className={`PaymentTyeBtn ${payOP.IsSelected ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"}`} onClick={()=> onSelected(payOP.ID)}>
      <img className = 'icon' src={`${payOP.IconImg}`}style={{position:'relative',top:'5%',marginLeft:'-4px'}}>
        
      </img>
      <p style={{display:'inline',position:'relative',top:'-5%',paddingRight:'5px'}}>
      {`${payOP.NameBrev}`}
      </p>
      </button>


    </li>
  )
}

function Inputlist({inputFields, currencyVal, tokenAmount,handleCurrencyChange, handleTokenChange}){
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: '5px',display:'flex', marginLeft:'11px'}}>
      {inputFields.map(field => (
        <InputField
          key={field.id}
          type={field.type}
          value={field.type === 'currency' ? currencyVal : tokenAmount}
          placeholder={field.placeholder}
          handleChange={field.type === 'currency' ? handleCurrencyChange : handleTokenChange}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function InputField({type, value, placeholder,handleChange}){


  return (
    <div style={{display:'inline'}}>
      <p>
        
      </p>
      <input
        className='ICOinputField'
        style={{display:'inline'}}
        type='number'
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

the wallet connect button doesn't work and I get this list of errors..
I keep trying to use chatgpt4o but I'm not getting anywhere!



there's even more errors than that but, all I can list in images.
I was having https://github.com/AlmostEfficient/full-stack-solana-dev/issues/3#event-12860788211 issue, did as it said but, now connect does nothing on my widget and throws these errors, this is all so complicated, if anyone here knows A LOT about solana dev and is willing to help me more hands on, please do. My discord is keolamation, same as here. I could really use some intense help atm.. I'm so behind on my project cause of this huge landslides or errors trying to implement the  /anza-xyz/wallet-adapter .

I don't use library anza-xyz adapter. But recommend uses API extension wallet in your browser will gets more complex but deep dive understand. Use with reducer and context to create you own store wallet adapter.
